# How to avoid TFS Build making folders Read-Only

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild, robocopy

We have used the following TFS Deployment strategy used for Websites -:

1) **Windows Machine File Copy**

**Source** : Folder of TFS
   **Target** : Application Server

Now, in a folder placed inside this website, files are first deleted and then added/ re-created.

But after deploying through TFS, files are made Read-Only. So files can't be deleted and error is thrown on the website.

How to handle this case in TFS deployment [image]    [image]

Comment: Did you mean you get an error using this step when clean the files under target folder during build? Could you please post the error message?

Comment: Files are getting converted to Read only after build which is why error is coming in screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Problem has been resolved by adding one attribute of Windows robocopy command.

**/A-:R**   : Removes the Read only attributes from copied files.

"/A" : attribute

"-"  : remove

"R"  : Read only property

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your build a server workspace or you are directly pulling files from TFVC into a server workspace ([see local vs. server workspaces](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace)). In a server workspace files that are not check-out are read in the workspace to prevent you from making changes locally without first telling TFS you are going to changes them (check-out). Since your build will usually not perform any source control operations in your workspace some or or all files remain read-only when you copy them or publish them as artifacts.

If you copy items from TFS to another location these read-only flags are also copied. However this is easily fixed by using `attrib -r` to clear the read-only flag either before publishing the artifacts from your build or before (or after) copying the files over to the target machine. See the [attrib](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490868.aspx) documentation for more options like recursion.

Comment: Done using the same principle of remove Read only property from the file. For robocopy, the arguement is /A-:R

Answer (score 0):

When you set a folder path as the Physical Path for a website in IIS 6.0, you will see that the folder are made to Read-only automatically.

You could remove the Read only setting for this folder in the folder property. If you want to remove the read only setting for your folder. In the [Windows Machine File Copy step](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy), you need to provide an account which is the administrator of the target machine.
[image]